# Can't get OpenCV + macam.component + PS3Eye working

Tags: opencv, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime

I have compiled OpenCV in 32-bit mode on MacOS with quicktime turned on and ffmpeg turned off.
My application is just a simple program to display the output of the webcam in a window. The application works perfectly with my built in iSight camera and the macam app works perfectly with my PS3 Eye but I can't seem to get them to work together.

The application works fine with the iSight

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

but when I try to use the PS3 Eye

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
```

every time I try to grab a frame off of the camera

```
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

I get an error message.

```
startNextBulkRead-ReadPipeAsync: Error: kIOUSBEndpointNotFound - Not found
```

I have been battling with trying to get OpenCV working with my PS3 Eye webcam for over a week but just can't seem to get it working. When I run the macam app, it takes captures from the camera perfectly so it just seems to be some sort of compatibility/configuration issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea why this works and was just trying to get a grayscale image from my eyesight so I added
    `frame = cvCreateImageHeader( cvSize(320, 240), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);`
and captured from cam 0 (which usually is my iSight) and it started grabbing from my PS3 Eye in full color...

Comment: Ok that actually only worked that one time...

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem (with Mac OS X 10.7.2 and the latest OpenCV). The behavior is totally erratic but the error message appears a lot more often than an image is successfully grabbed from the camera.

The situation for video capture on OS X is complicated, and we lack a decent cross-platform video capture library for real-time applications.

However, I advise you to go with [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/). It's a collection of libraries used mainly for interactive art and prototyping. While providing a lot of tools that are not necessarily useful if you just want to do some computer vision, there's OpenCV and a decent video capture facility that, from my experiments, works correctly with the PS3 Eye cam (and with a pretty good framerate).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it. I did several things so I don't know which one is the correct one, but this is what I did: updating os x to the last version, in my case now it is 10.7.3. Installing the last Xcode (with the apple dev tools and so, qt is the important thing), the version of Xcode I am using is 4.3.2. And compiling opencv to 32bits.

Comment: Were you able to get the camera running at the full 120 fps? Also were you able to run 2 cameras? I found that to run n cameras, I actually needed to have n+1 cameras plugged in.